# Upload new files to bucket from local drive

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I would like to write a script which will detect new files (csv files in this case) that have been added to a folder then upload these new files to my AWS S3 Bucket. I would like them to maintain the original name. Currently the script i have allows me to manually select a file then upload it with a name of my choice.

```
hc = pd.read_csv((open(r'CSV PATH')))

s3 = boto3.client('s3',aws_access_key_id = 'ACCESSKEYID',
     aws_secret_access_key = 'ACCESSKEY')

csv_buf = StringIO()

hc.to_csv(csv_buf, header = True, index = False)
csv_buf.seek(0)
s3.put_object(Bucket = 'BucketName', Body = csv_buf.getvalue(), Key = 'Original CSV Name from Above')
```

I assume i need the following section in the code:

1. Code to monitor said location (but only when running the app - does not need to run 24/7)
2. Code to pull new file from said location
3. Code to upload to S3 Bucket

Any Tips?

Comment: @Donal OP is already using boto3.

Comment: Is there some reason you're reading a CSV file and writing it back out instead of uploading the file as-is?

Comment: What do you mean by "new files"? New since a certain date, or do you mean "where such a file is not already stored in the S3 bucket"? By the way, do you know about the [AWS CLI sync command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html)? It can do exactly what you are seeking.